# Try/Catch not handling SQL Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sql, exception, try-catch, cluster-computing

> [ 13/11/2015 16:09:59 ] ERROR: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
>   (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

I am getting the above error very occasionaly when trying to open an SQL connection. The error is happening because the database cluster is busy syncing. My main issue is that the exception is not being caught by my try/catch and causing the application to crash. My code is below, the exception is being thrown on connection.Open()

```
 private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            ErrorMessaged = false;
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            if (MainInterface.Instance != null)
            {
                MainInterface.Instance.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }
            if (!ErrorMessaged)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        //Logs.AddToBugs("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        MainInterface.Instance.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    }));
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        //Logs.AddToBugs("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        MainInterface.Instance.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    }));
                        break;
                }
                ErrorMessaged = true;


            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try changing the MySqlException to Exception, see if it can hit the break point

Comment: yes your problem that you are trying to catch MySqlException but actually getting IOException, as User2012384 pointed just change it to Exception to catchh all exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a key "SynAttackProtect" in registry of type DWORD with value 00000000 at the location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\

Setting this registry key may expose the server to a SYN flood, denial-of-service attack. Add this registry value only if necessary and with an understanding of the security risks. Remove this registry value when testing is complete.

References: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005(v=sql.105).aspx